# Histogram error: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python

I am trying to create a histogram with the two dice rolled one hundred times and both of there rolls added together then added to a list and that list made into the histogram

```
def roll_hundred():
    b = []
    my_lover = range(101)
    my_lover1 = 1
    for my_lover1 in my_lover:
        if my_lover1 < 101:
            dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
            dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
            m = dice2 + dice1
            b += m
            my_lover1 += 1
    print (b) 
    plt.hist(b)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback. I'm confused what `my_lover1` is supposed to be doing here. It seems redundant throughout.

Comment: First indent your code properly

Comment: It is just a name I have to use a for loop so I set this so that it goes through it for as many times in the name my_lover1. That's why I add one to it each time till it's at 101

Comment: There is no line in this code which would cause the mentioned error

Comment: Except you don't need any of it. Except for `b = []`, get rid of `my_lover` and `my_lover1` completely and put everything inside `for x in range(101):`

Comment: But `plt.hist()` and `plt.show()` should not be inside the `for` loop, which they currently are. You want to plot only after the `for` loop completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes because you are trying to add an int `m` to a list `b`. In order to put a value in a list you need to append this by using `b.append(m)`.

In addition, you are calling `plt.hist()` after the first iteration. You need to move this, and `plt.show()`, outside of your for loop

Therefore your code would look like:

```
def roll_hundred():
    b = []
    my_lover = range(101)
    my_lover1 = 1
    for my_lover1 in my_lover:
        if my_lover1 < 101:
            dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
            dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
            m = dice2 + dice1
            b.append(m)
            my_lover1 += 1

    plt.hist(b)
    plt.show()

roll_hundred()
```

Which gives the figure:

[image]

Python values readability. The easier your code is to read, the better it is (in general). As @roganjosh said in the comments you can remove quite a lot of the variables in your code to make it more readable. You could (if you wanted to) do the following:

```
def roll_hundred():
    b = []

    for i in range(100):

        dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
        dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
        m = dice2 + dice1

        b.append(m)

    plt.hist(b)
    plt.show()

roll_hundred()
```

Comment: Thank you this worked exactly like i wanted it to thank you

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet, so here's an attempt at an answer/comment.

First, I notice you are making b into an empty list. Later on in the code, you try to add an int to the list. This causes the exact error. To test this, just open python's interpreter and try

```
b = []
b += 1
```

and you will get the error.

From what I see, try calling

```
b.append()
```

instead.

EDIT: Looks like a similar answer was posted just before I posted.

Comment: Thank you that worked it won't let me accept it for 7 minutes but thank you.

Comment: I would accept the other answer as it is far more complete than mine is.